# Entity framework - select nullable join property

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

My table structure looks like :

```
Account
 AccountId
 LoginName
 EmployeeId - nullable
Employee
  FirstName,
  SecondName,
  etc..
```

I have query :

```
   var data = from o in _accountRepository.AsQueryableWithIncludes(x => x.Employee, x => x.Permissions)
               select new AccountGridVM
               {
                   AccountId = o.AccountId,
                   EmployeeFirstName = o.EmployeeId == null ? String.Empty: o.Employee.FirstName,
                   LoginName = o.LoginName,
                   Permissions = o.Permissions.Select(s => s.NameCZ)
               };
    return View(new GridModel { Data = data });
```

My problem is in tenar operator in EmployeeFirstName, entity framework always fetch only accounts, which has employeeId assign, but i need fetch all accounts.

If i remove EmployeeFirstName propeprty, ef fetch all rows.

Where is problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `o.Employee == null` instead of `o.EmployeeId == null`?

Comment: Yes, try o.EmployeeId.HasValue, o.Employee == null, o.EmployeeId = null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I had mistake in mapping.

```
  //bad
  HasRequired(x => x.Employee).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.EmployeeId); // inner join

  //good
  HasOptional(x => x.Employee).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.EmployeeId); // left join
```